# What is the optimal method for multiple if/then's to evaluate a column's value in a dataframe and conditionally modify another column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (1580 rows x 48 columns) where each column contains answers to questions, but not every row contains an answer to every question (leaving it `NaN`). Groups of questions are related, and I'd like to tabulate the answers to the group of questions into new columns (`c_answers` and `i_answers`). I have generated lists of the correct answers for each group of questions. Here is an example of the data:

```
ex_df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "b", "d"],[np.nan, "a", "b"], ["c", "e", np.nan]], columns=["q1", "q2", "q3"])
correct_answers = ["a", "b", "c"]
ex_df
```

which generates the following dataframe:

```
    q1   q2   q3
0   a    b    d
1  NaN   a    b
2   e    c   NaN
```

What I would *like* to do, ideally, is to create a function that would score each column, and for each correct answer on a row (appears in the `correct_answers` list) it would increment a `c_answers` column by 1, for each answer that is not in `correct_answers`, it would increment a `i_answers` column by 1 instead, but if the provided answer is `NaN`, it would do neither (not counted as correct or incorrect). This function could then be applied to each group of questions, calculating the number of correct and incorrect answers for each row, for that group.

What I *have* been able to make a bit of progress with instead is something like this:

```
ex_df['q1score'] = np.where(ex_df['q1'].isna(), np.nan, 
                          np.where(ex_df['q1'].isin(correct_answers), 1, 100))
```

which updates the dataframe like so:

```
    q1   q2   q3   q1score
0   a    b    d    1.0
1  NaN   a    b    NaN
2   e    c   NaN   100.0
```

I could then re-use this code to score out q2 and q3 into their own new columns, which I could then sum up into a new column, and then from *that* column, I could generate *two more* columns which could calculate the number of correct and incorrect scores from that sum. Finally, I could go back and drop the other 4 columns that I created and keep only the two that I wanted in the first place.

Looking around and trying different methods for the last two hours, I'm finding a lot of answers that deal with one or another of the different issues I'm trying to deal with, but nothing that I could finagle to actually work for my situation. Maybe the solution I've kludged together is the best one, but I'm still relatively new to programming (<18 months) and it didn't seem like the most efficient or most Pythonic method to solve this problem. Hoping someone else has a better answer out there. Thank you!

**Edit for more information regarding output:** Regarding what I'd like the final output to look like, I'd like something that looks like this:

```
    q1   q2   q3   c_answers  i_answers
0   a    b    d    2          1
1  NaN   a    b    2          0
2   e    c   NaN   1          1
```

Like I said, I can kind of finagle that using the nested `np.where()` to create numeric columns that I can then sum up and reverse engineer to get a raw count from. While this is *a* solution, its cumbersome and seems like its probably not the optimal one, especially with the amount of repetition involved (I'll have to do this process for 9 different groups of columns, each being a cluster of questions).

Comment: How looks expected final ouput?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added the desired output, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` for count `True`s values for correct and incorrect values per rows:

```
m1 = ex_df.isin(correct_answers)
m2 = ex_df.notna() & ~m1

df = ex_df.assign(c_answers=m1.sum(axis=1), i_answers=m2.sum(axis=1))
print (df)
    q1 q2   q3  c_answers  i_answers
0    a  b    d          2          1
1  NaN  a    b          2          0
2    c  e  NaN          1          1
```

Possible solution for multiple groups:

```
groups = {'g1':['q1','q2'], 'g2':['q2','q3'], 'g3':['q1','q2','q3']}

for k, v in groups.items():
    m1 = ex_df[v].isin(correct_answers)
    m2 = ex_df[v].notna() & ~m1
    
    ex_df = ex_df.assign(**{f'c_answers_{k}':m1.sum(axis=1), 
                            f'i_answers_{k}':m2.sum(axis=1)})
print (ex_df)
    q1 q2   q3  c_answers_g1  i_answers_g1  c_answers_g2  i_answers_g2  \
0    a  b    d             2             0             1             1   
1  NaN  a    b             1             0             2             0   
2    c  e  NaN             1             1             0             1   

   c_answers_g3  i_answers_g3  
0             2             1  
1             2             0  
2             1             1
```

Comment: This will work for the entire row, but my original dataframe is 1580 x 48, with several different groups of questions, each of which has to be compared to their list of answers. So this won't work for me, unless it can be sliced to work on certain columns.

And, as mentioned, I'd really like to actually get the count of correct answers and incorrect answers (both matter, but NaN's do not). This method works similarly to the one I came up with using `np.where()`, but I'd still have to reverse engineer the raw counts.

Comment: @WJTownsend - Answer was edited, can you test?

Comment: That only works if the answers are the same for all question groups. An answer in group 1 that is correct may not be correct in group 2. That's why I figured a function would be ideal, because it could be fed a particular list of correct answers, and a list of the associated questions. I ended up just doing it the more cumbersome way that I came up with before. It may not be the most Pythonic way, but it works. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @WJTownsend - My problem is not understand what need. How are defined groups? Like `groups = {'g1':['q1','q2'], 'g2':['q2','q3'], 'g3':['q1','q2','q3']}` ? Because in question is missing this info.

Comment: The question only presented one group, and there are 9 other groups in the actual dataframe. Like g1 = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3'], g2 = ['q4', 'q5', 'q6'], and so on.

Comment: @WJTownsend - Sure, so change in my solution `groups = {'g1':['q1','q2'], 'g2':['q2','q3'], 'g3':['q1','q2','q3']}` to `groups = {g: ['q1', 'q2', 'q3'], g2: ['q4', 'q5', 'q6']}` and working solution well.

Comment: No, because you're still using the `m1 = ex_df[v].isin(correct_answers)` in the middle of the loop. Each question group has its own set of answers, and what's correct in one group is not necessarily correct in the other. Again, that's why I was trying to come up with a function based solution, where I could feed in a slice of columns (say, the ones that constitute group 1) and the appropriate list of correct answers. I appreciate your trying to help, but at this point, the project is already done, whether the code is "pretty" or not.

Comment: @WJTownsend - hmmm, so no information how are defned values per groups, so how I can guess values per groups are different? From text I try using `groups = {'g1':['q1','q2'], 'g2':['q2','q3'], 'g3':['q1','q2','q3']}`, what partly working, because need also defined correct answer per each group. It for me missing in question, so cannot use in answer, unfortuantely. Happy coding.